# How can I do Taxi missions without waiting?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

I've beaten Story Mode in GTA 5, and I've bought the Downtown Cab Company. I want to do these special missions right away.

Do I have to sleep a lot to try do make time pass? Is there any way to get these missions faster than once a week?

Comment: Have you tried calling the cab company from your phone, as far as i know the missions are completely random

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure you need to be in a cab at the Downtown Cab Company.
Here's an easy way to do it:

- Call Downtown Cab for a cab.
- Carjack the cab and take it to the Downtown Cab. It should ask you if you want to start the missions.